# Conditional Breakpoints in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, conditional-breakpoint

In a relatively large VB.NET application, I have the following code.

[image: code]

The code sits within a `for loop` that runs for every given **service object**. I want a conditional break point that will only activate when `objService.VehLastMile` is **Nothing**.

So I right-click my break point and add a condition, here it is:

[image: condition]

But this does not work! my break point is not hit! what am I doing wrong?

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: `Is Nothing`, not `= Nothing`.

Comment: Thanks that was it, please reply as Answer! ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `=` operator doesn't work for a value of nothing in VB.NET

You should either use the [`Is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx) operator:

```
objService.VehLastMile Is Nothing
```

Or [`IsNothing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5adx7fxz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function:

```
IsNothing(objService.VehLastMile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like when you are coding, if you want to compare a *reference* type to Null (Nothing) you have to use `Is` so your condition should be:

```
objService.VehLastMile Is Nothing
```

You can compare *value* types to nothing using the equals sign, but this is effectively the same as comparing it to `[Type].MinValue`

See [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c)